# Adding node to last coordinate

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I have a loglog plot and would like to highlight the last coordinate. For example

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{loglogaxis}[]
\addplot+[] coordinates{(0,0) (2,20) (3,100) (4,4000)};
\end{loglogaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I want a node **only** on the last coordinate showing a value of 4000. 
The option `nodes near coords` does not what I want since it displays all coordinates and only their log values.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To labels points with their untransformed coordinate values, you can make those values available using `visualization depends on=rawy \as \pgfplotspointrawy`. To only label the last point, you can simply add `node [anchor=south] {\pgfmathprintnumber[1000 sep=\,]{\pgfplotspointrawy}}` at the end of the `\addplot` command:

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{loglogaxis}[visualization depends on=rawy \as \pgfplotspointrawy]
\addplot+[] coordinates{(1,1) (2,20) (3,100) (40,4000)} node [anchor=south] {\pgfmathprintnumber[1000 sep=\,]{\pgfplotspointrawy}};
\end{loglogaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```